# Customize X axis - Kendo UI

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

I have implemented the following project. There are two lines on the chart.

However, I want to change position of x axis to move 0 at the center.

```
                    seriesDefaults: {
                        type: "scatterLine",
                    },
                    series: [{
                        name: "Path1",
                        data: stats,
                        markers: {
                        visible: false,
                        color: 'red'
                       }
                     }, {
                        name: "Path2",
                        data: stats2,
                        markers: {
                          visible: false
                        }
                    }],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/13/

I need to customize x axis and reverse the datasource to display as follows:
[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

All I did is to add the following lines of code:

```
min:-5000,
axisCrossingValue: [-5000, 0],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/19/